# Random garbage characters from math array

Tags: math-mode, rendering

I'm getting weird results with this math-mode code:

```
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{H} = {\left[ \begin{array}{c:c} \mathbf{I}_{r \times r} & -\mathbf{P}^{T} \end{array} \right]} \Rightarrow
\mathbf{G} = {\left[ \begin{array}{c:c} \mathbf{P}_{k \times r} & \mathbf{I}_{k \times k} \end{array} \right]}     
\end{equation*}
```

which produces some garbage characters when rendered:
[image]

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Comment: At least for me that is not a MWE. Please make sure your MWE contains all information that allows to compile it.

Comment: Using `:` in the argument to `array` is not allowed by default, so you should add the necessary packages for trying and reproducing your issue.

Comment: If you want the colon as a column separator, try wrapping the colon in a @{:} and see if that fixes the issue. You may (or may not) also want to adjust the space around the colon.

Answer (score 1):

Is the following (close to) what you want?

[image]

The `:` notation in `array` environment is non-standard; if it's important to the look of the math material, you should indicate how it's set up.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'bmatrix' and 'equation*' environments
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \mathbf{H} = 
  \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{I}_{r \times r} & -\mathbf{P}^{T\,} \end{bmatrix} 
  \quad\Rightarrow\quad
  \mathbf{G} = 
  \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{P}_{k \times r} & \mathbf{I}_{k \times k} \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm almost sure that it's just a dashed line attempt

Comment: @percusse - Thanks. It would be helpful if the OP weighed and expressed what the `:` character is supposed to represent.

Comment: Life is not fair :)